# Angular structure for Common sharing component

Tags: json, angular, typescript, interface

The scenerio is like I need to load a 2 component with same shareable component, but the form will have many form fields same, but some will differ as per the component . What structure I need to create in angular.

On click I am only able to see the common form but I dont know how to show the different data on clicks

Comment: Give us more infos and show a little code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.